Is United Healthcare the fourth largest company by market capitalization in the USA?
As published by Ken Klippenstein, in _"Exclusive: Luigi's Manifesto"

United [Healthcare] is the [indecipherable] largest company in the US by market cap, behind only Apple, Google, Walmart. It has grown and grown, but as our life expectancy?

Is it true that United Healthcare is the fourth "largest company in the US by market cap, behind only Apple, Google, Walmart"?

I'm not sure that a claim where the important bit is undecipherable meets the noteriety requirement for this site.  That said, you can pull up a list of companies by market cap https://companiesmarketcap.com/usa/largest-companies-in-the-usa-by-market-cap/ and and see UnitedHealth at #15.  But that position would fluctuate with the market so it is entirely likely that it has been #14 at times.

I don't think it's relevant "largest company in the US by market cap, behind only Apple, Google, Walmart" stands on its own

Does it? Is the claim that it is the largest? The 3rd largest? The 10457762th largest? I mean it will be one of those, by definition. Any company will be the Nth largest if we can find the right value of N.

@terdon The second half 'behind only Apple, Google, Walmart' only makes sense if the first part says 'fourth largest', so that is by far the most likely interpretation.

Close. In the recent past (beginning of 2023) it was the 6th largest company in the US by market cap. You could argue it was 5th at that time, if you wanted, because Berkshire Hathaway is principally a holding company. It was behind Apple, Google, Amazon, and Microsoft.
However, it is the 4th largest US company by revenue, behind Walmart, Apple, and Amazon. According to their shareholder report they had $370b in revenue in 2023, they spent $240b on health care, and had an operating profit of $30b.
This overall seems to be an irrelevant thing to be skeptical of, as market cap can fluctuate reasonably quickly and the core premise of the surrounding argument does not appear to be changed if UHC is the 4th or the 5th or the 6th largest company by market cap in the united states.

I agree whether or not it's the fourth or fifth isn't material. But I'm shocked it's top 50. I had no idea UH was that big of a company. Especially by market cap, what does it even own? It's a service company. I would have though Popeye's Chicken was bigger. That is to say your assignment of the skepticism is misplaced, I had no idea a health insurance company was worth 500 B. For comparison HCA is #61, I would have assumed HCA was WAY bigger than UH. HCA actually provides the care and they OWN 186 Hospitals and 2,000 care sites.

According to UHC it took in $370b in 2023 and turned that into $240b of health care spending plus $30b of operating profit, and is the 4th largest company in the US by revenue.

So where did the remaining 100B go?

93B went to "Operating costs and costs of products sold" according to the shareholder report, with a couple other smaller line items like depreciation

@EvanCarroll Health care in total is something like 15 or 17% of US total GDP. It's huge, much bigger than say the car industry. It is not that surprising that some companies in that sector are among the biggest companies overall.

@EvanCarroll Market capitalisation has little to do with ownership of physical assets. Neither Apple nor Microsoft own large factories, for example. Their huge profitability matters and the bulk of that comes from, in effect, software which is largely non-physical these days.
